# UITableView left margin checkmark buttons - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, accessory

I'm trying to add check marks to my UItableview cells. I want to checkmarks to display like circle buttons on the left margin like this image:

[image]

I am unable to get the checkmarks in the left margin with my code and instead I keep getting checkmarks on the right that display only when tapped. Here is my current code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

}
}
```

Any idea on how i can get the checkmarks to display on the left like the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made for you whole sample application for this.

[just try this.](https://github.com/junaid4058/messages)
And this is what it looks like.
[image]

Comment: Hope you can convert it to swift.:) It's just a language.

Comment: oh! i made it and i forgot. :)